Gradle upgrade renames source files
During the migration from Gradle 6.x to Gradle 8.x, I encountered an issue where Gradle, during build process, automatically appended “_1” to source files with the same name but located in different directories. I am using JetBrains IntelliJ IDE and gradle plugin to build the project.
I found a useful reference on GitHub. I tried the solution mentioned on that page, but unfortunately, it didn’t work. The most compelling solution appears to add the following in build.gradle:
rootProject.tasks.named("processResources") {
duplicatesStrategy = 'include'

}
However, this doesn’t prevent Gradle from renaming the resource file. Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Note :- The files that are being renamed are located inside a folder directly under the root folder of the project. I’m uncertain whether the task name ‘processResource’ is appropriate in my case.

What do you want it to do with duplicate resource files? Simply overwriting every time doesn't seem like a robust approach since the build order may change, and hence which file is overwritten. Maybe you should tackle the source of the duplicates

@SimonJacobs These are fake duplicates. This is basically plugin that supports dark and light theme of IDE. Resource files for dark themes are kept under directory structure for exaple...somePath/dark/somefile.html. Similarly for light theme path would be somePath/light/somefine.html. Although the name of the file is same but their location and the content of the file are different. Hope this makes sense.

On re-reading, I see this seems to be happening to files that are in different directories. That doesn't seem like a duplicates issue then, but a somewhat strange bug. I can't see what would be causing that. In your shoes, I'd be carefully looking at what the build steps were, eg seeing what tasks were running and looking at their output using the -i flag
